# Could I mix Unity with iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, uiview

I have questions about Unity and iOS.

1) Could I put Unity program into iOS UIView?

2) Could I get data of variables from Unity program in iOS app?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES and YES 
- You can imbed your unity view into any Navigation Controller , and you can pass variables from your iOS app into unity app .
 Here is a demo project with the functions you will need 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ElDzo1Uno14bM0cKNThMTC6KOUjDl8Hb/view

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [integrating Unity as a library in a native iOS app](https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-ios-app.685219/).

However Unity suggests:

> ...that you deeply understand the architecture of Android/Java & iOS/Objective C applications.

Before doing so